# How to send an image from node.js node-fetch?

Tags: node.js, forms, image

I want to send an image from node.js script A to another node.js script B (server file).
I want to send it as `application/octet-stream`.

In A I have this

```
const contents = await fs.promises.readFile('car.jpg', {encoding: 'base64'});
await fetch("http://localhost:3002/edit?filter=" + JSON.stringify([{a:1}]), {
    method:"POST",
    body:"=data:application/octet-stream;base64," + contents,
    headers :{ 
        'content-type' : 'application/octet-stream'
    }
});
```

And in B, I have

```
const upload = multer({
    limits: {
      fileSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024,
    }
});

var app = express();
//app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

...

app.post("/edit", upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
    try { 
        //var params = req.body;
        var params = JSON.parse(req.query.filter);  
        console.log(params);
        console.log(req.body, req.file);
        var buffer = Buffer.from(req.body, 'base64'); // base64  binary
        console.log(buffer);

        res.end();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

The car image is 894 KB.

But I don't get any image data. I want to get the Buffer data. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can send an image to the server over node-fetch **without using any other package** as follows:

In A file:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

const contents = await fs.promises.readFile('test.jpg');
let base64data = contents.toString('base64');

await fetch("http://localhost:3002/edit?filter=" + JSON.stringify([{ a: 1 }]), {
    method: "POST",
    body: base64data, //simple change here
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'
    }
});
```

And to get a buffer data in the B file (I haven't changed any other parts of your code):
Added : `app.use(express.raw({ type: 'application/octet-stream', limit: '2mb' }));`

```
var app = express();
//you needed it
app.use(express.raw({ type: 'application/octet-stream', limit: '2mb' })); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.post("/edit", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        
        var params = JSON.parse(req.query.filter);


        var buffer = Buffer.from(req.body,'base64'); 
        console.log(buffer)

        res.end();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

And output:

```
<Buffer 2f 39 6a 2f 34 41 41 51 53 6b 5a 4a 52 67 41 42 41 51 45 41 59 41 42 67 41 41 44 2f 34 54 44 4b 52 58 68 70 5a 67 41 41 54 55 30 41 4b 67 41 
41 41 41 ... 115606 more bytes>
```